# в .htaccess перенаправлять все запросы в index.php

Tags: .htaccess

нашёл в интернете вот такой вод:

```
 php_value default_charset utf-8 
 RewriteEngine on   
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|vendor|images|assets|img|my|sys|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

во всех случаях работает, но когда ввожу в адресной сроке браузера запрос вида:
`http://mydomain.com/country/oteli-indiji`, выводит 404 ошибку. Методом тыка, понял, что ошибку выдаёт именно из-за слова `country`, не могу понять почему.

Цель: абсолютно все вводимые запросы `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` должны передаваться в `index.php` для дальнейшей обработки.

Comment: у вас там есть папку country. может из этого. думаю нужно удалить  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Comment: такой папки нет, есть файлы типа: country
country_bolgarija.php
country_egipet_kair.php
country_egipet_sharm-el-sheih.php

Comment: файл `country` совпадает с `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: если убрать RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f, то перестают подгружаться стили в выводимых через index.php

Comment: папки стилей можно прописать так `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|vendor|images|assets|robots\.txt)`

Comment: всё-равно что-то не так, вот что получается: http://hotel-apartment.biz/country/gostinici-belarusi-otzivi

Comment: в список добавили `my` `sys` `img` ?

Comment: да, получилось RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|vendor|images|assets|my|sys|robots\.txt)

Comment: вставьте последный вид htaccess в вопсрос обновлением

Comment: исправил исходный вопрос с обновлённым .htaccess

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32949/discussion-between-valextt-and-saidolim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после обсуждений в комментариях

в папке был файл `country` и из этого не работали ссылки `http://mydomain.com/country/oteli-indiji`

Предложено переименовать файл country на другое

Comment: Вопрос решён! Спасибо Saidolim за помощь!